# Looking for a cross platform small footprint database

Tags: database, select, c#-4.0, mono, cross-platform

I have the following scenario. I need a db to store XML messages that have been created by a reader. I then want to use a transport (wcf) to read the db external to the populating app and send the messages to a central db Generally the db needs to run on mono, and windows.

I did look at sqlite3, and it seemed to fit all my requirements, but i'm reading its not so good on multi process access and t's moving away from my sweet spot, these last couple of days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just using XML to store the data? It doesn't get any more portable than that and will work fine as long your client-side storage needs are simple. E.g. not a large amount of many domain objects that need to be stored.

Additionally using an XML data store solves a lot of setup and installation headaches. You simply reference a file (or files) relative to your executable. You don't need to worry about installing db engines for a variety of platforms and then worry about upgrading.

Comment: You know, that not a half bad idea. They are essentially xml messages. Each one in a seperate file, encyrpted.

Comment: Yeah, XML seems to have lost some credibility as a storage mechanism or even as a messaging structure and often gets overlooked but there are definitely times when it "fits the bill" nicely. This may be one of them.

Comment: Is XML old hat. Whats replaced it? JSON

Comment: XML isn't old, or replaced. It's just not as favored as it used to be. And yes, JSON is used often over XML when size matters because it is much less verbose therefore smaller and lighter. Btw, JSON could work for you too but it's hard to recommend that specifically without knowing your specific needs.

Comment: Its set in stone. They bigish xml, 20k to about 140k. Fairly sizable messages. I notice the number of question tagged xml on stack is 17k, and json 8k.

Answer (score 1):

WOuld it be feasible to give each process their own sqlite3 database?  They all ultimately use the central database anyway, right?

Comment: How would you do it. I'm newish (3 days) to sqlite.

Comment: @scope_creep: In the same way that you did it for the one process?

Comment: standard multiple connections from different processes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/).

You can use it as an embedded engine just like SQLite, but it can scale to a full blown server as well.

The only drawback is, that the documentation is a mess

Comment: your no kidding with the docs.

Comment: @scope_creep: unfortunately I'm not kidding... But otherwise Firebird is really a nice DBMS. But most probably you don't need a RDBMS anyway...

Comment: your no kidding is a scottish phrase, your not kidding, i.e. your telling the truth.

Comment: It would take too long to wade through the docs.